# PHP pages that will end with the .HTML extension using .htaccess file on Apache

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have a 2 year old static HTML and CSS website. The site has over 150 pages and it's too much work to keep it updated (like sidebar content, menu, head section or footer).

So now I want to convert my static HTML and CSS website to PHP (and use php includes), but because of SEO reasons (backlinks to my site) I want to keep the .html file extension.

Example:

www.example.com/malware.php becomes www.example.com/malware.html

Before I used Server Side Includes, but found out that SSI's cause security problems like SSI injections (happened to me).

My website is hosted on A2 Hosting (TURBO shared hosting account) https://www.a2hosting.com/web-hosting/compare.

Which lines of code in the .htaccess file can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your answers, but i just found the solution after searching for awhile. I've just included the following lines in the .htaccess file and it works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Comment: But that will simply redirect all `.html` addresses to `.php`, you did state *I want to keep the .html file extension*.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: OP did specify **keeping** the `.html` extension, not simply redirecting to `.php` alternatives.

Comment: Yes. But the OP also said his motivation was retaining the .html is URL's for SEO reasons. This solves that problem.

Comment: But it is simple to do __without__ changing the URLs.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins : See the example he is given .I hope this solves his problem

Answer (score -1):

There are two different ways to have Apache interpret `.html` as `.php` and handle them as such.

Normally, you'd use this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html .htm
```

But I've found for some shared hosting accounts, you need to adjust this command, and use the following.

```
AddHandler cgi-script .html 
SetEnv PHP_EXTENSION .html
```

Do bear in mind that this will increase the server load for your website, but unless you do something very stupid (which your host will protect against) you should be fine.

You can perform a 301 redirect as outlined in these other answers, and Google will certainly re-index your website fairly quickly. However there will be a couple of weeks of your website's position in the search result fluctuating.